# How to check to see if a node in a tree either has 0 or 2 children?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I was wondering how I go about the logic of this. How would I know if a node has 0 or 2 children? This is what I have so far, checking to see if node t has a left and right child.

```
public static boolean hasChildren(Node t) {
    if (t.left == null && t.right == null){
       return true;
    }
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a condition that is true when `left` and `right` are both `null` or when they both are not `null`. This can be expressed like this

```
if (t.left == null && t.right == null) {
   return true;
}
if (t.left != null && t.right != null) {
   return true;
}
return false;
```

like this

```
if ((t.left == null && t.right == null)
||  (t.left != null && t.right != null)){
   return true;
}
return false;
```

like this

```
return (t.left == null && t.right == null)
    || (t.left != null && t.right != null);
```

or for serious geeks, like this:

```
return (t.left == null) == (t.right == null);
```

The last expression warrants some discussion, because it compares `left` and `right` to `null`, and then compares the results of these two comparisons between themselves to produce the final result.

To see if all nodes in the tree has 0 or 2 children you would have to do it recursively:

```
public static boolean isLeafOrHasTwoChildren(Node t) {
    // Both nulls
    if (t.left == null && t.right == null) {
        return true;
    }
    // One is null, the other one is not null
    if (t.left == null || t.right == null) {
        return false;
    }
    // Recurse down the tree
    return isLeafOrHasTwoChildren(t.left)
        && isLeafOrHasTwoChildren(t.right);
}
```

Comment: no problem. I also have another question, I'm sorry I just want to make sense of my questions. What if a node with 2 children is only valid if (size-of-larger-child <= size-of-smaller-child * 3) ? would you need to find the max and min of a node?

Comment: @yummyyenni The problem based on tree sizes is a lot harder. You would be better off storing counts in the nodes to avoid re-computing them all the time. You may want to try solving this first, and then post another question if the solution does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need something like this:

```
public static int hasChildren(Node t) {
    if (t.left == null && t.right == null){
       return 0;
    } else if (t.left != null && t.right != null){
       return 2;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }

 }
```